# active directory dns - how forward external hostname

Tags: dns, active-directory

I have a normal configuration of dns of active directory with suffix .intranet.local

Now We buy a software for a chat that need to solve the same hostname from internal and external...so in my public internet domain .company.com my ISP have create the new host chat.company.com corretly and this work from external users.

The problem is only for my internal users...If in my in dns of AD i create a new zone .company.com and insert chat.company.com all work ...but all other record no (www, FTP, etc..) because this is configured in the ISP dns.
Is possible in MS dns ...create the zone only for .company.com and all other records that isn't listed...forward to public ISP dns?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to set up conditional forwarding, where your AD DNS services local/intranet requests by either answering directly (in the case of another local server), or forwards the request to the "Live DNS Server" in the wild to get the latest information, in the case of subdomains served outside of the intranet.

Check out this technet article on forwarders (and conditional forwarders):
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782142(v=ws.10).aspx

And here's another link that shows you, notionally, how to configure your AD to do conditional forwarding:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773370(v=ws.10).aspx